# Email not send when put order for recurring profile products

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order, recurring

I placed the order for recurring profile products. New order email not received. If I put the order for normal products, I received the email.How to fix this. Is any option in backend to enable this?

Comment: What is the status of that order in the backend? If you turn on logging anything in system or exception logs?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I customized to send mail for recurring product order

Comment: You mention that you have customised something to send the email so for anyone to help it would be good to see what you have customised. Also with what payment method are you using recurring profiles? Any other extensions installed?

Comment: can u please tell me how did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

So there could be two parts here that are causing the problem. Firstly the easiest is that when magento completes an "order" in the sense of the normal frontend checkout process it does not actually send an email for the recurring profile by default.

You can see this in the function `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder` at the bottom you will see the note:

```
// TODO: send recurring profile emails
```

Yeah well I guess this is one of the reasons for the beta flag on the recurring profile extension.

The second thing you could be talking about is that on the recurring payment trigger the emails is not sent but for this we would need to know what payment you are dealing with.

Basically you need a payment type that uses `Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface`. This will have its own functions for creating orders and at this point you can trigger the emails yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you had more then one product in the order this could be the problem. An order with a recurring profile product can one have that single item in it.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

Comment: I had only one item in cart.

Comment: Did you verify to see if the email was sent but just not received?